# If I create a Postgres index what's the difference between ASC and DESC?

Tags: postgresql

Does it mean ASC is better for queries such as

PRICE > 40

and DESC is better for queries such as

PRICE < 40?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The where condition might not be affected, but the ORDER BY is definitely affected

[PostgreSQL Index Ordering Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/indexes-ordering.html)

Comment: This is the important bit: *An important special case is ORDER BY in combination with LIMIT n: an explicit sort will have to process all the data to identify the first n rows, but if there is an index matching the ORDER BY, the first n rows can be retrieved directly, without scanning the remainder at all.*

Comment: @Milen A. Radev Thanks for pointing it out, fixed to point in released version. I think Google might have answered the OP question as well though.

Answer (score 10):

PostgreSQL (or any other DB engine, for that matter) will read your index in either way fine. You'll get an index scan or a reverse index scan.

The problem is when you've got a multi-column scan. In this case:

```
index on (foo, bar)
```

will work for `foo asc, bar asc`, as well as `foo desc, bar desc`. On some databases this will not work on `foo desc, bar asc` (reverse scans foo, ignores bar), or `foo asc, bar desc` (scans foo, ignores bar).

Comment: So what is the difference? If I have a query `WHERE foo = X AND bar > Y` does that mean I need a `foo, bar desc` index? Or is it vice-versa? Or does DESC's purpose lie in some other kind of queries?

Answer (score 2):

Descending can give you a boost if the column(s) contain sequencial data that is referenced by "recent" values -- date columns, ID columns , etc.

Generally speaking, the tables/indexes would have to be really large for it to make a difference, though.

It won't affect what gets returned, just how.